# Template selector within data template uwp

Tags: c#, listview, mvvm, uwp-xaml

I have a listview with a ItemTemplateSelector to load my custom datatemplate based on a model. I'd like to know if i can use another TemplateSelector inside the main DataTemplate to load another Datatemplate to change the listview item DataTemplate based on the same model.

#### Main ListView

```
 <ListView
        Padding="10"
        Grid.Row="1"
        ItemsSource="{Binding DbObjectList, Mode=TwoWay}" 
        IsItemClickEnabled="True"
        ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource TemplateSelector}"
        x:Name="Comps">
```

#### Main DataTemplate

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="SetupDataTemplate" x:DataType="data:Setup">
        <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="{x:Bind text}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" FontSize="16" />
            <ContentControl Grid.Column="1" Content="{Binding}" ContentTemplateSelector="{StaticResource SetupTemplateSelector}" />
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Text="{x:Bind key}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" FontSize="16" />
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
```

I tried to use ContentControl/ContentPresenter to load the DataTemplate i want, but the Content property is always NULL.

```
 <ContentControl Grid.Column="1" Content="{Binding}" ContentTemplateSelector="{StaticResource SetupTemplateSelector}" />
```

#### SetupTemplateSelector

```
protected override DataTemplate SelectTemplateCore(object item, DependencyObject container)
    {
      .....
    }
```

I need to pass the Listview item to SetupTemplateSelector to choose my DataTemplate.
Is it the right way to do that?
Are there better solutions to solve my problem?
If you need more just ask!

Thanks

Comment: [`ContentTemplateSelector`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.contentcontrol.contenttemplateselector(v=vs.110).aspx) is of `DataTemplateSelector` type. It's not a simple template as you think, but a custom class you write (it's small) which supply template. See [this tutorial](http://www.wpftutorial.net/datatemplates.html).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, my problem using contentcontrol, is about binding content property, "object item" parameter is always null, in my SetupTemplateSelector class.